# SQLite Select SUM Rolling Window

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this table in SQLite

```
Table [Ticks]
Fields: 2
    [Value]: INT
    [Time]: DATETIME
```

And I want to select a window or partition of 10 hours of values and make a sum of those values then move one row forward and do the same for last 10 hours through the whole range of records.

The value field contains -1 or 1

How can I achieve this? Is this possible with the WINDOW, PARTITION query?

Comment: What is the format of the column `Time` and what is your version of SQLite?

Comment: @forpas it is DATETIME, SQLite 3.36

Comment: There is no DATETIME data type in SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: @forpas this is the SQL CREATE statement from DB Browser for SQLite CREATE TABLE [Ticks](
  [Value] INT, 
  [Time] DATETIME)

Comment: With SQLite in the CREATE TABLE statement you can use anything for a data type, even nothing and it will be allowed. Try `CREATE TABLE tablename(Time imaginarydatatype)`. It works. My question is how do you store the dates in your table? Is it integers (unix times),  or floats (julian days), or strings and if they are strings what is their format?

Comment: At this link  sqlite.org/datatype3.html if you look down on the page there is a DATETIME, it is stored as NUMERIC, but SQLite will convert to DATETIME for SQL query compatibility

Comment: This is about affinity. If you define a column as DATETIME its affinity will be NUMERIC. This does not mean that the column has DATETIME as data type and certainly SQLite does not convert the values to DATETIME because there is no such data type. Read the documentation carefully.

Comment: @forpas as long as I can query that column like a DATETIME field I think it gets converted otherwise I would get a number instead of datetime

Comment: No, you would not get a number. SQLite's type system is different than other databases. You can store **anything** in a column defined as INTEGER or DATETIME. When you query the table you get what you store. If you stored a string you get a string. If you stored a number you get a number. Anyway, the link of the documentation is there. You can read it. My question was what is the format of the dates that you store in the table and after so many comments you have not answered yet.

Comment: @forpas UTC time, this is how the value looks 2020-12-13 20:04:19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `time` to seconds and then use `range()`:

```
select t.*,
       sum(value) over (order by strftime('%s', time) + 0
                        range between 35999 preceding and current row
                       ) as sum_10hours
from ticks t;
```

The `strftime()` expression converts the value to seconds.  The range takes (10*60*60 - 1) seconds before to the current row.

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) is a db-fiddle.

Comment: sum_10hours contains the exact same value as the value field 1 or  -1, it does not sum the values

Comment: @Mario . . . The string result from `strftime()` needs to be converted to a number, so I just added `0` to it.

Comment: Now the sum_10hours contains the sum of only the current and last row, and each row was recorded at every 5-10minutes, so the sum of 10 hours should contain the sum of approx 100-120 rows